# Missing event owner in Calendar API response

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using the Calendar API and when I call the 
`event['creator'].get('email')`
I'm always getting the email, and it's all working the right way.
When I call 
`event['creator'].get('displayName')`
or 
`event['organizer'].get('displayName')`
I'm having the same result with both (and it's fine), but sometimes I get the right result (name and surname), sometimes I get "null" or "none" as result.

I noticed I can fix it adding a Google+ profile for the user, after adding a G+ profile the response will provide the right name and surname, but it's not the right solution for us.
From Google Calendar the name and the surname of every event owner are correctly displayed.
I started from this: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

```py
for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime',event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, 
            event['summary'],
            event['creator'].get('email'),
            event['creator'].get('displayName'),
            event['organizer'].get('displayName'))
```

I expect to have the creator displayname to be the same as shown in the Google Calendar event, not to be = "none".

**Example.**

What I want:
09.00 GMT+2, example event, john.doe@test.com, John Doe, John Doe

What I have:
09.00 GMT+2, example event, john.doe@test.com, none, none

[Event from calendar is displaying my name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyDYK.jpg)

[API Response is showing "none" "none" instead of my username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l1cK.jpg)

**Sample event dictionary:**

```
2019-06-17T14:00:00+02:00 BOA - verifica report mariachiara.l@example.com None None

2019-06-17T16:00:00+02:00 CID Dunning letters lara.@example.com None None

2019-06-17T17:00:00+02:00 Hangouts call with Elisa pietro.m@example.com None None

2019-06-18T08:30:00+02:00 New building update gianluca.n@example.com Gianluca N Gianluca N
```

Comment: Can you show how a sample `event` dictionary looks like @Andrea and do you thing the data is actually missing from the Calendar API ?

Comment: Done! I hope that's what you asked. Thanks

Comment: I mean post the contents of your `events` list in the question and not links @Andrea :)

Comment: I wrote a test example if that what you asked, anyway you can find a real example in the screenshots in the 2 links (I can't post images directly here as a new member). Thanks

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I added the content of my event list, I hope it's what you asked. Thanks

Comment: Sorry It's out of my expertise